# Selecting child records from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a "company" table, which has a relation with the table "companycategorylink", which has a relation the the "category". I have a query where I can select all companies based on the company ID. I have a field in my category table which identifies the parent category, so that I can have nested categories. I just had to make a change to my design though, where you can now "merge" categories. You can mark a category as "merged" by setting a flag in the parent category. Basically so that multiple categories show as one. The thing is, that I now also have to select all companies linked to all the merged categories linked to the parent category, and at the same time also have it still work for none merged categories. It shouldn't break non merged categories. I have no idea how I would go about doing this. As I'm required to post a code snippet of what I currently have, here it is:

```
SELECT company.Name AS CompanyName, company.Description, company.Logo, company.CompanyID, company.Telephone, company.Fax, company.Address, company.City, category.Name, category.CategoryID
FROM company
JOIN categorycompanylink ON categorycompanylink.CompanyID = company.CompanyID
JOIN category ON categorycompanylink.CategoryID = category.CategoryID
JOIN company ON category.Combined = 1 
WHERE category.CategoryID =19
```

It's obviously incomplete though, but I'm completely stuck. How would I go about doing this?

This is my category table:
[image]

And this is my company table
[image]

Any help is appriciated. I have no idea how to continue

Comment: Use aliases for the tables. Keywords to search for: `self-join`, `table alias`.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry the first is not applicable in my case, as I have no idea how to do this. I'll try and provide a result set. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Without Step 1, don't bother with step 2. It won't mean anything to us.

Comment: ".. I can select all companies based on the company ID", did you mean category id? I find your question confusing and agree, that you need to show example data and expected result.

Comment: As a first step I suggest you abandon your category design and replace your hierarchical categories with a nested set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model and http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not be what you were looking for (please rewrite your question) [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f344f/3).

The final query:

```
select * from (
  select node_category.* from category as parent_category
    join category as node_category on node_category.lft between parent_category.lft + 1 and parent_category.rgt - 1
    where parent_category.id = 2
        and node_category.merged
  union
    select * from category where id = 2) as category
  left join company_has_category on category.id = category_id
  left join company              on company_id = company.id;
```

with the tables:

```
create table company (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(20) not null
);
insert into company values (default, 'company 1'), (default, 'company 2'), (default, 'company 3');

create table category (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(20) not null,
  merged bool not null default false,
  lft int not null,
  rgt int not null
);
insert into category values 
 (1,  'Electronics',          false, 1,20),
 (2,  'Televisions',          false,  2,9),
 (3,  'Tube',                 false, 3,4),
 (4,  'LCD',                  true, 5,6),
 (5,  'Plasma',               true, 7,8),
 (6,  'Portable Electronics', false, 10,19),
 (7,  'MP3 PLAYERS',          false, 11,14),
 (8,  'Flash',                false, 12,13),
 (9,  'CD Players',           false, 15,16),
 (10, '2 Way Radios',         false, 17,18)
;

create table company_has_category (
  company_id int,
  category_id int,
  constraint foreign key (company_id) references company (id),
  constraint foreign key (category_id) references category (id)
);

insert into company_has_category values (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2);
```

Some queries to help you understand how it works:

```
-- the data
select company.*, company_has_category.*, category.* from company_has_category
  left join company on company.id = company_id
  right join category on category_id = category.id;

# id, name,        company_id, category_id, id, name,                merged, lft, rgt
1,    'company 1', 1,          1,           1,  'Electronics',       0,      1,   20
2,    'company 2', 2,          1,           1,  'Electronics',       0,      1,   20
1,    'company 1', 1,          2,           2,  'Televisions',       0,      2,   9
3,    'company 3', 3,          2,           2,  'Televisions',       0,      2,   9
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        3,  'Tube',              0,      3,   4
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        4,  'LCD',               1,      5,   6
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        5,  'Plasma',            1,      7,   8
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        6,  'Port. Electronics', 0,      10,  19
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        7,  'MP3 PLAYERS',       0,      11,  14
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        8,  'Flash',             0,      12,  13
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        9,  'CD Players',        0,      15,  16
NULL, NULL,        NULL,       NULL,        10, '2 Way Radios',      0,      17,  18


-- the children of category 2 (without the parent) which have their merged flag set
select * from category as parent_category
  join category as node_category on node_category.lft between parent_category.lft + 1 and parent_category.rgt - 1
  where parent_category.id = 2
        and node_category.merged
;

-- the children with merged set plus the parent
-- (if the parent has her merged flag always set, the union can be dropped)
select node_category.* from category as parent_category
  join category as node_category on node_category.lft between parent_category.lft + 1 and parent_category.rgt - 1
  where parent_category.id = 2
        and node_category.merged
union
  select * from category where id = 2;
```